# I need to convert a Pandas df to a text string with tab delimited separation and multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas

Convert a Pandas Dataframe to a text string with comma delimeters and multiple rows

```
df = df.to_string()
email.send(text=df)
```

df columns = No Client_Name Warehouse_Area Location OEM

Expected result = No,Client_Name,Warehouse_Area,Location,OEM

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to convert dataframe object to tab separated string

```
df_string = dataframe.to_csv(index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple just use [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to output string

```
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df_string = df.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n')
vals = [','.join(x.split()) + '\n' for x in df_string]
email.send(text=vals)
```

Comment: I have multiple rows and its making them all a single line how do i keep them as seperate rows?